# How to implement UIVibrancyEffect for table view header?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiblureffect, uivibrancyeffect

I would like my table view section headers text to be rendered in the vibrant style, where the underlying UI shines through the text. I have tried the following, but nothing appears for the header as if I returned `nil`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    //Add vibrancy text effect
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
    let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)

    //Label for vibrant text
    let vibrantLabel = UILabel()
    vibrantLabel.text = "testing"
    vibrantLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11.0)
    vibrantLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.64, alpha: 1)
    vibrancyEffectView.contentView.addSubview(vibrantLabel)

    return vibrancyEffectView
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. The only problems with my code provided in the question are: I had to set the frames for the view and label (duh), and I needed to specify the blur effect style to be `.Dark` not `.Light` to ensure the text was light colored not dark. For anyone who has the same question, here's the code. You'll want to tweak the position/size/etc of the text I'm sure. Note that I already had applied a blur effect for the table view's background.

```
//Create vibrancy text effect
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect)
let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)
vibrancyEffectView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 40)
vibrancyEffectView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth

//Create header label
let vibrantLabel = UILabel()
vibrantLabel.frame = vibrancyEffectView.frame
vibrantLabel.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
vibrantLabel.text = "testing"
vibrantLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
vibrantLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.64, alpha: 1)

vibrancyEffectView.contentView.addSubview(vibrantLabel)
return vibrancyEffectView
```

[image: image of the final effect]